# How to display more than 10 articles on a contact page with Show User Articles enabled - Joomla

Tags: php, joomla

In Joomla 2.5, there's an option to list an Author's articles on their contact page ("Show User Articles"). However, I'm only able to get it to list the most recent 10 articles - I can't find a setting in the parameters to change this, so I figured I'd take a crack at changing the code in `/ components / com_contact / views / contact / tmpl / default_articles.php`, but I'm at a loss.

Here's the file:

```
<?php
/**
 * @package     Joomla.Site
 * @subpackage  com_contact
 * @copyright   Copyright (C) 2005 - 2012 Open Source Matters, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * @license     GNU General Public License version 2 or later; see LICENSE.txt
 */

defined('_JEXEC') or die;

require_once JPATH_SITE . '/components/com_content/helpers/route.php';

?>
<?php if ($this->params->get('show_articles')) : ?>
<div class="contact-articles">

    <ol>
        <?php foreach ($this->item->articles as $article) : ?>
            <li>
                <?php echo JHtml::_('link', JRoute::_(ContentHelperRoute::getArticleRoute($article->slug, $article->catslug)), htmlspecialchars($article->title, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8')); ?>
            </li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ol>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

`helpers/route.php` is much longer but I'll include it here if need be.

What would be causing this to limit the list to 10 items? Is there a way to paginate additional results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't used joomla but had a quick look at it, if you go to 
components\com_contact\models\contact.php

Find these lines:

```
$db->setQuery($query, 0, 10);
$articles = $db->loadObjectList();
```

This is where it querys the db for the articles.

Havent tested it out but that should be it.

Comment: Don't know how I missed that, but thank you, that must be it. Will